# java8 stream concatenate map output to string return java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

Hi I'd like to extract and format attributes from object steam and concatenate them in a new string.

Ex

```
public class User{
   public User(String name, String lastname){
      this.name = name;
      this.lastname = lastname;
   }
   public String name;
   public String lastname;
}


List<User> memberNames = new ArrayList<>();
memberNames.add(new User("john", "rush");
memberNames.add(new User("peter", "gabriel");

String users = "";

users += memberNames.stream().map(user ->{return String.format("The user name is %s and his lastname is %s\n", user.name, user.lastname); });
```

but when i try to print users string

```
logger.info(users);
```

I obtain

```
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@396555a1
```

instead of

```
The user name is john and his lastname is rush
The user name is peter and his lastname is gabriel
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have a small typo in your code: `List<User> memberNames` instead of `List<String> memberNames`

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@396555a1
```

is the outcome of trying to print the `Stream` you have created until the `map` operation performed.

You are looking to `collect` the user names mapped until now while joining then with a `\n` delimiter.

```
String users = memberNames.stream()
        .map(user -> String.format("The user name is %s and his lastname is %s", user.name, user.lastname))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(users); // to print them all at once
```